# Is it possible to add pdf to cms-pages

Tags: admin, cms, file-upload

I want to link some legal documents (in PDF format) in the terms and conditions page, and I can't find an option to upload them there.
Is it possible to upload them inside magento or should I look elsewhere?

Comment: You could upload the file to your server (ssh/ftp) then link to the pdf file from your cms page. Also see http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/embed-pdf-document-website/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MDNsolutions did a [blog post](http://blog.mdnsolutions.com/index.php/enable-pdf-extension-on-wysiwyg-for-magento/) about this. It will enable PDF upload via the media gallery. I've used it before but on an older shop so I can't guarantee it'll work in a later version of Magento

If that doesn't work, have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9900787/387136). It explains how to create a widget that accepts an image but might also work for PDF.

Answer (score 1):

There's no ability to upload anything other than images for use on CMS pages - it's likely there is an extension which already does it though.

Answer (score -2):

You could redirect an url in the CMS page to the location of your PDF file on the server